How to Mount a NAS to Linux Server WITHOUT the Server considering the Mount as part of its storage? (Disk Space low even when Server still has plenty)
I have an Ubuntu Server with 128GB, 28GB is free.
I mounted a Synology NAS to the Server at the folder /home/NAS/media using fstab.
192.168.0.88:/volume1/Stash /home/NAS/media nfs auto,defaults,nofail 0 0

While the Server still has 28GB of free storage, the NAS with 8TB of storage is actually full. For some reasons, the NAS being full prevents the Server from performing any tasks even with the 28GB free of storage, as "There's no efficient disk space." error appears for pretty much all operations, such as sudo apt upgrade, etc. Unmounting the NAS will solve this problem.
Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I assume this is because the Server thinks it has less than 1% disk space left, even though it actually has more than enough to perform any tasks. If that's the case, how do I tell the Server to stop worrying about the NAS storage, or thinking that the NAS is actually part of the system that would have any affects on the system besides being a pure storage?
Below you can see the screenshot with the simple mkdir command that doesn't work because there's not space.

It looks like the nvme is full, but it was mounted on /. How does this even work, because my / shouldn't be full at all? I tried running ncdu / to see what is taking so much space, but I couldn't find anything:

Even it's showing full, /home has 833.9GB of data coming from the mounted NAS folders /home/NAS. The server itself is not at all near being full.

With that said, I unmounted the NAS when the problem occurred, and run df -h again. This is the result. Apparently, the nvme still has 41GB of space left.


I've never had apt care about space in /home...

@vidarlo: I would think so too, but somehow when the drive is mounted, the system always says "insufficient disk space", but unmounting it immediately solves the disk space problem. That makes me think my Server actually cares about the NAS storage for some reason.

Can you quote the exact message you get? Wording, punctuation, and all. Do you get the same message from all programs or do different things show different messages?

@u1686_grawity: Hello. I shall post the update in a day. Usually the system is fine after a reboot if the problem occurs, but after one day, that's when the disk space problem happens. I'll have to wait for a day for it to happen.

Include df -h in the question.

I believe it's something like /tmp being filled... df -h is always the first to do if such problems occur. Also df -i may be useful; "insufficient disk space" may mean "no free inodes left" rather than "no free extents left" which is how people often understand the message.

@u1686_grawity: I've updated my question with screenshot.

@NikitaKipriyanov I've updated my question with df -h. Is there anything I can check?\

That df -h definitely looks like your rootfs is full. Unmount the NAS, then do the ncdu again. (Specifically, do ncdu -x /. The NAS is really irrelevant here – df directly queries each filesystem about its capacity, so if df says your disk is full, that means your disk is full.)

@u1686_grawity I have a question. So why does unmounting the NAS help? As stated in the post, unmounting the NAS will solve the problem until one day later. Why is the disk is full when there are actually space left in the server (after unmounting the NAS)?

Can you prove that there is space left in the server? I mean your df shows otherwise, and the way it gets its information means it basically ignores any sub-mounts.

@u1686_grawity I edited the question with the updated screenshot of df -h after unmounting the NAS.

Right, okay. Can you install fatrace (e.g. from https://github.com/martinpitt/fatrace) and do a cd / && sudo fatrace -c . running before you mount (or before you unmount)?

Would also be curious to see what you get from: unshare --mount --propagation=private and then as a separate command mkdir /run/root; mount --bind / /run/root; ncdu -x /run/root
